# seeking iOS sidur

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, phone

I am considering upgrading my iPhone from iOS version 10 to version 11. If I do so, I will lose the use of my current *sidur* (prayer book) app, which doesn't work on iOS 11. So I'm seeking recommendations for another. Each recommendation should please include (among other things) an indication of which of the following criteria the app meets and how it does so:

- The *sidur* should include *nusach "S'farad"* (like *chasidim* use, or similar, but I don't mean *nusach Chabad*). Ideally, it should contain *only* such a *nusach*, or have the option to hide undesired *nuschaos*, so as to minimize confusion.
- It should include everything recited on a weekday *mincha* and *maariv*, such as "*Yaale v'yavo*", "*V'al hanisim*", "*Anenu*", "*Vaanenu bore olam*", *tachanun*, "*Dirshu Hashem b'himatz'o*", "*Avinu malkenu*", Psalm 27, and Psalm 49. It should allow easy access to such things as are said from time to time, ideally without being intrusive. (If it has *birkas hamazon* too, so much the better. That it have *Shacharis* is not important to me, but I don't mind it.)
- It should be free of charge.
- It should have a table of contents or the like, for quick tapping to the appropriate part of the *sidur*.
- It should not translate or transliterate prayers. Alternatively, it should have the option to hide such translation/transliteration.
- It need not have instructions.

Comment: Which siddur (app) are you using now?

Comment: @Yehoshua https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/siddur-nusach-sefard/id299971206?mt=8

Answer (score 5):

I have used [RustyBrick](https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/rustybrick-inc/id286478370)'s [iOS siddur](https://www.rustybrick.com/iphone-siddur.php) for years. Here is how it fares against your criteria:

- it has all nusachim (ashkenazim, sefard, edot hamizrach, chabad) and you can choose which one you want at any point in time (i.e., it only shows one at a time)
- it has all prayers recited on any weekday, incl. special days (e.g., fasts, Rosh Hodesh) - it has an option to only show what you need to see on that day (they call it smart siddur)
- it has birkat hamazon and all other blessings
- it has a table of contents, and you can jump between sections of a prayer service
- it has optional English translation

Helpful additional features you don't mention are a Jewish calendar, a list of *zmanim* (times for prayer) for all locations in the world and (optional) reminders for mincha.

Only issue is that it costs 9.99$ - well worth it in my view but more than you asked for.

Comment: The Luach Events function of the calendar is great for tracking yartzeits, births, anniversaries and other auspicious days of history.

Answer (score 2):

The siddur in the [Apple app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onyourway-%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%9A-%D7%91%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A-%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%92%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99/id449507485?mt=8). 'OnYourWay - ובלכתך בדרך' fits these criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [RustyBrick’s Siddur app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/siddur-zmanim-luach-minyanim/id286478367?mt=8), though I know that the [Sefaria app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sefaria/id1163273965?mt=8) also has a Siddur.